# CubicCurve and CubicCurveTo in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to create a JavaFx desktop application, and I want to draw some shapes. In order to draw this shapes I want to use bezier cubic curve. I noticed that in JavaFx there exists CubicCurveTo and CubicCurve.  What are the main differences between `CubicCurveTo` and `CubicCurve` in `JavaFx`?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html). One is a `Shape` subclass, and one is a `PathElement` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CubicCurve` is a subclass of `Shape`, so it is a fully functional `Node` in the scenegraph. `CubicCurveTo` is a `PathElement` which is not a `Node` and cannot be added to the scene graph; instead you add `CubicCurveTo` to a `Path`, which is a `Shape` and may be added to the scenegraph.

So if you just want to add a cubic curve to the scene graph, you'd likely go with `CubicCurve`, but if you were creating a more complex geometry that consists of more than just a single cubic curve, you would use a `Path`, adding one or more `CubicCurveTo`s to it, perhaps along with other `PathElement`s.